# Regex to allow only integers, decimals, plus and minus characters

Tags: android, regex, validation

I'd want to trigger a form validation alert if the string isn't like "8+" or "8-" or "8++" or "8--" or "8.5". I'm struggling to find a regex matching something like this.

Comment: "thanks" is mere fluff here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `^\d(?:([+-])\1?|\.\d)$` matches all your numbers.

Formatted:

```
 ^ 
 \d 
 (?:
      ( [+-] ) \1? 
   |  \. \d 
 )
 $
```

Comment: Works well. Is it possible to not match "8+-"?

Comment: @Androider - Changed, won't match `8+-` now.